# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' - bash simple script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am learning Raspberry Pi and trying to use code to read my CPU temperature and save it to a file with a bash script. The code is here:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
cpu=$( $(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)"
far=$((cpu/1000))
far2=$((far*9))
far3=$((far2/5))
far4=$((far3+32))
echo "CPU => $((cpu/1000))' C or $((far4))' F"
echo ""
echo "Pi temp $far4 degrees F" > /var/www/html/pitemp.txt
```

Here is the error:

```
$ sudo chmod +x checkTemp.sh
$ ./checkTemp.sh

./checkTemp.sh: line 10: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./checkTemp.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$ _
```

Why is it wrong? Here is [the instruction I follow](https://nebulousthinking.wordpress.com/2019/07/27/displaying-your-raspberry-pis-temperature-on-its-home-web-page/).

Comment: That is not a good tutorial. (a) It even gets the shebang wrong -- missed the first character. (b) You did copy the `cpu=` line from it verbatim -- that's wrong too. (c) It does not explain that you need to make the script executable.

Comment: You might like to visit `shellcheck.net`. You can validate any shell script in detail -- either online, or download the tool. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line doesn't look right

```
cpu=$( $(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)"
```

you probably want something like

```
cpu="$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)"
```

`$(command)` is used to run command from a script, having the opening `$(` and ending the line with a quote `"` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: thanks very much for correct and teaching.:D

Comment: Thanks @RomanRiabenko, I update the answer.